# Automated alternative to Visual Studio's batch build?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-processing

I have a managed library that wraps a native library which has binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Currently, I have to do the following:

First, build the native library 32-bit and 64-bit builds using [Batch Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-build-multiple-configurations-simultaneously?view=vs-2022).

Second, build the managed library.

The managed library references binaries which are then loaded using [NativeLibrary.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativelibrary.load?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-nativelibrary-load(system-string)) at runtime.

The whole thing ends up as a NuGet package ready for consumption.

**Question:**

How can I get that batch build step to be performed automatically instead of manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<MSBuild Projects=.../>` just works, the key in getting this to work is:

- get the projects to compile through command-line to figure out missing parameters

  - not as straightforward as it sounds as Visual Studio does a lot under the hood
- finally, pass the required parameters to `<MsBuild>`, e.g. `OutDir` for instance

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe VS has the ability to directly have a project depend on multiple platform builds of a different project. It's possible to make an x64 project depend on an x86 build but not, as far as I am aware, have it depend on both x86 and x64 builds of a single project.

You could, however, add a duplicate project. That is, have your dependency rely on x86 build of foo_x86 and x64 of foo_x64, with foo_x86 and foo_x64 actually building from the same files. It may even be possible to have foo-_x86 and foo_x64 actually use the same project file. That last I am simply not sure about.